# Global menu and HUD suddenly broken

Tags: hud, globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global menu not showing in Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222070/global-menu-not-showing-in-ubuntu-12-10-with-unity)

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for about three months now and I am very satisfied, it is highly usable and stable. Even though I didn't like the global menu at first, I've grown to appreciate its added screen real estate.

But, some update or some piece of software recently broke my global menu / appmenu.  Every application reverted to displaying the menu bar at all times, even when maximized. Besides that, the HUD has stopped working, so it seems like the applications are no longer able to provide the menu information to the global menu indicator / whatever it is.

I am quite clueless as to what caused this bug / regression. Here are the things I have tried:

- Reset Unity and the Compiz Plugin with `unity --reset`
- Uninstalled and reinstalled `appmenu-`{`gtk3`|`gtk`|`qt`} (`sudo apt-get remove blah && sudo apt-get install blah`)
- Use Unity 2D session to check whether it is somehow caused by "regular" Unity
- Searched with `gconf-editor` for some menu related settings that may have been corrupted, but nothing significant came up or I wasn't sure what the option did

Do you have any clues? What could have caused this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new account on the machine to see if it might be specific to that particular user? If it works, it'll at least give you a point of A/B comparison, or you could copy your home directory to USERNAME.old, and then transfer files back (assuming the new account works).

Comment: I have verified that this doesn't work. Also, I encountered the same problem. It seems that after toggling "HUD" in Ubuntu Tweak Tool, global menu breaks. Turning "HUD" back on in Ubuntu Tweak Tool doesn't fix global menu. I'm on Unity 12.10.

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/215352