# Global Menu broken for Gnome Applications after adding GNOME 3 PPA

Tags: unity, gnome, globalmenu

After using the GNOME3 PPA to upgrade Nautilus , (I have been working with it for several days without problems), the Global Menu broke for all Gnome-application, like `totem`, `gnome-terminaL`, `nautilus` 3.4, etc...).
At the same time, when I launch any of these applications from terminal, I get the following error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:62:17: Theming engine 'unico' not found
```

I purged the GNOME3 PPA, re-updated, auto-cleaned, dist-upgraded, downgraded Nautilus, reinstalled the `gtk3-engines-unico` and `appmenu`, but in vain.

[image]

Anyone has a clue of fixing this?

```
~$ apt-cache policy gtk3-engines-unico
gtk3-engines-unico:
  Installed: 1.0.2+r139-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.0.2+r139-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2+r139-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

~$ apt-show-versions gtk3-engines-unico
gtk3-engines-unico/quantal uptodate 1.0.2+r139-0ubuntu2
```

The Unico issue seems to be known [in RR.13.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk3-engines-unico/+bug/1077568).

I have Installed gtk3-engines-unico from RR-13.04, to see if it fixes the issue but in vain. Now I get a different error message when running a Gnome application from Terminal:

```
Failed to load type module: (null)

menu_proxy_module_load': /usr/bin/python:
undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load
```

But what about 12.10?

Comment: Probably happening because `gtk3-engines-unico` is either out of date or too new.

Comment: I have the version which is in the archive. It's not outdated.

Comment: Ok, then yes it is :). That is because the _rest_ of GNOME is updated to a newer version (via the GNOME 3 PPA), but `gtk3-engines-unico` isn't. You see what I mean?

Comment: I see. I already purged the GNOME3 PPA. but that did not help. I updated, checked if these Gnome Apps like totem or Gedit are newer than those in Quantal archive and it seems, not.

Comment: Try running the system upgrades (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I already dist-upgraded, but in vain.

Comment: This question has also been asked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/222070/global-menu-not-showing-in-ubuntu-12-10-with-unity and discussed in launchpad here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/215352

Answer (score 1):

Ok. **Solved the problem.**

The problem came from **libgtk-3-0**. A *newer* version (3.6.2) than the one in quantal archive ( 3.6.0-0ubuntu3.2 ) was still kept in the system.

Actually, the GNOME3 PPA purging when I first did it, was not performed correctly due to a bug in the **ppa-purge** package in quantal official archives (multi arch bug). So I :

- installed a new version of ppa-purge which fixed the bug.
- re-added the GNOME3 PPA again : `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`.
- ran ppa-purge again : `sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

It downgraded all the packages installed from GNOME3 PPA to the ones from the official quantal archives.

- A logout was necessary for changes to take effect.

Comment: There was an issue with the GTK package in the GNOME 3 PPA but it was fixed... Now the global menu should work.

Comment: @AlinAndrei Thanks for pointing this out. I'd retry with with the PPA again.

Comment: I can confirm that it's been fixed.